# Ktor + React project configuration

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, gradle, ktor

I'm trying to start my first web project. My experience is with .NET desktop development and I'm very new to the Java/Kotlin world. Client side I want to use React and write the code in Kotlin, then transpile to JavaScript. Server side I would like to use Ktor both to serve the static content (React app + various assets) and REST endpoints for the SPA. I would like to use the Multiplatform feature to be able to share as much code as possible. My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA.

I would like to have auto-reload and be able to debug both React and server code for development and I would like to be able to create a single fat jar with the complete application (frontend+backend).

I started with the template that IntelliJ provides for multiplatform JS+JVM. I have been working on it for more than one day with little success and also haven't been able to find any sample online with all the features, and also haven't been able to combine various samples due to insufficient knowledge. Only thing I got is either running the application without autoreload or creating the jar file by adding "manifest" to the build.gradle file which breaks my run configuration.

I would very much appreciate if someone could provide or point me to an example with these features which I can use as an starting point for my application.

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project? I'll try to figure out how to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to an example to get you started.

https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Full%20Stack%20Web%20App%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/01_Introduction